# Sessions with the same name conflict

Tags: php, session

I have 2 applications on my server, each use $_SESSION['user']. If I am logged into one, I am automatically logged into the other application. The problem is that both sessions use different ids, so I automatically log into my partners account. How do I prevent this from happening without having to change the session names.?

Comment: You can't. Either change domains so the session cookies (and sessions) don't conflict, or change session names. That or change the apps so it's `$_SESSION['app1']['user']` and `$_SESSION['app2']['user']`.

Comment: Sessions with the same name, on the same domain, do not "conflict" - they are fundamentally the same session.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
session_name('ses_mysite');

session_start();
```

its working for me :)

or use

```
session_set_cookie_params();
```